# Decoding unnamed JSON array swift 4 with structure

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have been trying to decode an array for an app where I have to decode JSON.

I just can't decode it with my actual structure and others which I tried before.

Here are my latest structures:

```
struct peticion: Decodable{
    let datos_conexion: datos_conexion
    let estado_lanzamiento: estado_lanzamiento
    let usuario: usuario
}

struct datos_conexion: Decodable {
    let conexion: datosConexion
}

struct datosConexion: Decodable{
    let datos_conexion: String
}

struct estado_lanzamiento: Decodable{
    let tiempo_restante: String
    let etapa_actual: String
}

struct usuario: Decodable {
    let Id: Int
    let Nombre: String
    let Password: String
    let Imagen: String
    let Puesto: String
    let Departamento: String
}
```

JSON full example from Request

```
[
    {
        "datos_conexion": {
            "conexion": "2019-05-27 17:05:45"
        }
    },
    {
        "estado_lanzamiento": {
            "tiempo_restante": 240,
            "etapa_actual": "Configuracion"
        }
    },
    {
        "usuario": [
            {
                "Id": "4",
                "Nombre": "This is the Name",
                "Email": "email@gmail.com",
                "Password": "1234",
                "Imagen": "default.jpg",
                "Puesto": "",
                "Departamento": "Etapa Final"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

decoding code

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url2) { (data, resp, err) in
    guard let data = data else{return}
    let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
//      print(dataAsString)
    do {
        let JSONDATA = try JSONDecoder().decode([peticion].self, from: data)
//     print(data)
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("cant decode", jsonErr)
    }
```

Errors trying to do this:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
>
> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode dictionary but found an Array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON? This structure makes no sense. Why an array of dictionaries where each dictionary has one key? This top level should be a single dictionary containing the three keys.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but class, struct, and enum names should start with uppercase letters. Variable, method, and case names should start with lowercase letters. All should use camel case, not underscores. Use coding keys to map JSON keys to properly named properties.

Comment: In response of Maddy question, that is the point of this exercise, learning how to solve this kind of problems with the JSON, and I don't have control over it, that was made by my professor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your JSON, you are receiving an `[[String: Any]]` which is `Array` containing `Dictionaries` of `Any` values and `String` keys. This is tricky, since the dictionaries are containing values of `Any` which is not Decodable. Also, the container is `Array`, usually we would have a `Dictionary` as the container.

Normally, we would simplify this response.. But we cannot on this scenario.

One way to decode this is:

```
struct Peticion: Decodable{
    let datosConexion: DatosConexion
    let estadoLanzamiento: EstadoLanzamiento
    let usuario: [Usuario]

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        //unkeyed because we are getting an array as container
        var unkeyedContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let datosConexionWrapper = try unkeyedContainer.decode(DatosConexionWrapper.self)

        let estadoLanzamientoWrapper = try unkeyedContainer.decode(EstadoLanzamientoWrapper.self)
        let usuarioWrapper = try unkeyedContainer.decode(UsuarioWrapper.self)

        datosConexion = datosConexionWrapper.datosConexion
        estadoLanzamiento = estadoLanzamientoWrapper.estadoLanzamiento
        usuario = usuarioWrapper.usuario

    }
}


//use wrappers to handle the outer dictionary
struct DatosConexionWrapper: Decodable{
   let datosConexion: DatosConexion

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
      case datosConexion = "datos_conexion"
   }
}

struct DatosConexion: Decodable{
   let conexion: String
}



struct EstadoLanzamientoWrapper: Decodable{
  let estadoLanzamiento: EstadoLanzamiento

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
      case estadoLanzamiento = "estado_lanzamiento"
   }
}

struct EstadoLanzamiento: Decodable{
   let tiempoRestante: Int
   let etapaActual: String

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tiempoRestante = "tiempo_restante"
        case etapaActual = "etapa_actual"
    }
}

struct UsuarioWrapper: Decodable{
  let usuario: [Usuario]

}

struct Usuario: Decodable{
   let id: String
   let nombre: String
   let email: String
   let password: String
   let imagen: String
   let puesto: String
   let departamento: String


   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case nombre = "Nombre"
        case email = "Email"
        case password = "Password"
        case imagen = "Imagen"
        case puesto = "Puesto"
        case departamento = "Departamento"
   }
}
```

Decoding code //i only changed the decoding type to my Peticion struct

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url2) { (data, resp, err) in
    guard let data = data else{return}
    let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
//      print(dataAsString)
    do {
        let JSONDATA = try JSONDecoder().decode(Peticion.self, from: data)
//     print(data)
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("cant decode", jsonErr)
    }
```

This was a fun exercise. This is also untested code, but I'm pretty sure it would work.

Answer (score -3):

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - WelcomeElement
struct WelcomeElement: Codable {
    let datosConexion: DatosConexion?
    let estadoLanzamiento: EstadoLanzamiento?
    let usuario: [Usuario]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datosConexion = "datos_conexion"
        case estadoLanzamiento = "estado_lanzamiento"
        case usuario
    }
}

// MARK: - DatosConexion
struct DatosConexion: Codable {
    let conexion: String
}

// MARK: - EstadoLanzamiento
struct EstadoLanzamiento: Codable {
    let tiempoRestante: Int
    let etapaActual: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tiempoRestante = "tiempo_restante"
        case etapaActual = "etapa_actual"
    }
}

// MARK: - Usuario
struct Usuario: Codable {
    let id, nombre, email, password: String
    let imagen, puesto, departamento: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case nombre = "Nombre"
        case email = "Email"
        case password = "Password"
        case imagen = "Imagen"
        case puesto = "Puesto"
        case departamento = "Departamento"
    }
}

typealias Welcome = [WelcomeElement]
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong and it explains how the answer resolves the issue. Please edit your answer and provide details beyond fixing naming conventions and adding coding keys.

Comment: how do I access welcomeElement properties with this method? what it does instead of the struct? thanks for your response